# How to Navigate from one View to another View using MVVM

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have two scenarios to call one View from another View, Normally we do code behind Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)) to call other page, but I don't know how to do this using MVVM.

1. I am on Login Page and I want to call MainPage on Button click whose operations are obviously in ViewModel. So from ViewModel I want to navigate to different View.
2. On MainPage I have left frame and right frame where I will put two different pages. So I want to navigate those two pages on two different frames in one page.

If anyone can tell me about how it works, using one example or article, will be more helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Navigation in MVVM is well described for example on the [MVVM Light framework blog](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/nav1.cshtml).

Usually it is best to use an existing MVVM framework, which already provides a navigation service that can be easily used to bootstrap navigation without the need to do it manually.

To the second request - to have to distinct navigation frames, you will probably need to have a custom navigation service in which you will be able to specify the "target" - if you want to navigate to a view model in the left or right frame. Both frames will then have their own navigation history you will need to manage them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Which MVVM framework are you using? If you are using Galasoft MvvmLightLibs you need to use Messenger.Default.Register and Messenger.Default.Send.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/magazine/jj694937.aspx

From the viewmodel you can send a message (your custom class) that contains all the informations required for the navigation (destination page and related parameters, for example). Before sending the message, you need to register the message: in this place you specify the method to run when a particular message is receveid.

In this way, you can easily make communication from the viewmodel to the UI layer of your application.

Comment: The question is not about communication but about the `INavigationService` of MVVMLight. The Messenger is not required for this, it only makes things easier if you want to send data from one VM to another VM.

Comment: The user didn't specify which MVVM toolkit is using, I hope that is MvvmLightLibs! :-)

Comment: MVVM pattern is new for me, I don't know which framework I should use. I am doing project on Universal Windows app, can you please suggest me, which MVVM framework should I use.

Comment: I suggest Galasoft MvvmlightLibs, but it's my opinion. It's well supported by WPF, UWP, Xamarin. You can find it on NuGet.